# Why when adding scrollbar to editorwindow it's throwing error You are pushing more GUIClips than you are popping?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

GUI Error: You are pushing more GUIClips than you are popping. Make sure they are balanced.

```
Vector2 scrollPos;

void OnGUI()
{
if (allChildren != null && allChildren.Count > 0)
        {
            EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
            scrollPos =
                EditorGUILayout.BeginScrollView(scrollPos, GUILayout.Width(100), GUILayout.Height(100));
            for (int i = 0; i < allChildren.Count; i++)
            {
                allChildren[i] = EditorGUILayout.ObjectField("Transform " + i.ToString(), allChildren[i], typeof(Transform), true) as Transform;
            }
            EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't close the scrollview.

This line solved it :

```
EditorGUILayout.EndScrollView();
```

Code :

```
private void OnGUI()
    {
        if (allChildren != null && allChildren.Count > 0)
        {
            EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
            scrollPos =
                EditorGUILayout.BeginScrollView(scrollPos, GUILayout.Width(400), GUILayout.Height(400));
            for (int i = 0; i < allChildren.Count; i++)
            {
                allChildren[i] = EditorGUILayout.ObjectField("Transform " + i.ToString(), allChildren[i], typeof(Transform), true) as Transform;
            }
            EditorGUILayout.EndScrollView();
            EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
        }
    }
```